# Where can you defined ng-controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can someone please explain why ng-controller inside a plain HTML element will work, but if I write it inside a directive it will not work?

For example, this one will work:

```
<button ng-click="doThis()" ng-controller="myCtrl" />
```

Clicking on this button will find doThis() function inside myCtrl, works great.

BUT -

```
  <buttonDirective ng-click="doThis()" ng-controller="myCtrl" />
```

This will not work. The directive will not be rendered at all on page.
For this to work I need to rap it with div like that:

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <buttonDirective ng-click="doThis()" /> 
    </div>
```

Why? Should every directive be rapped with an element with ng-controller?
What if I have multi directives inside another directive, each one should be rapped with its own ng-controller div?

Comment: I think that you cannot have 2 directives on the same DOM element that require an isolate scope. `ng-controller` does so. I guess `buttonDirective` also does.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem: my directive get objArr which is defined in the Controller. Something like that: <buttonDirective ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-click="doThis()" data-obj="objArr" />
now objArr is json declare in this controller...

Comment: Here is example: http://plnkr.co/edit/573t7NNBvRefrCEEJLrY?p=preview
you can see I wrote two option - ng-directive inside a div or inside the directive itself. Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else is in play here.

What do you have the scope set to in your directive? Are you specifying a controller in your directive JS code?

[Here's an example Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FcWzXQL6Xe15UR0LvgIu?p=preview) showing both examples you provided working side-by-side (altered from the Angular site).

So, to answer your question, you can have the controller in three places:

#### 1) Directly on the directive markup

```
<buttonDirective ng-click="doThis()" ng-controller="myCtrl" />
```

#### 2) Wrapping the directive

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <buttonDirective ng-click="doThis()" /> 
</div>
```

#### 3) In the Javascript

```
.directive('dir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: "name" // or function
  };
});
```

Comment: What if my 'code' <buttonDirective some-data="arrObj" ng-click="doThis()" /> 'code' is getting some-data attr which declare in controller and this data he needs in order to create the directive? like a list (json format) he must get in order to create a dynamic list.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: Think you have written a DropDown directive. The directive gets input data (json string) and the data inside the dropDown is being created dynamically defends on the data list. Each raw in json is an option inside the dropDown. Every one can create its own dropDown directive, just changing the data given. Now, where should this data json format be? I have put it inside the controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer saying that it was the priority was wrong as SamP pointed out.  Just like he said, there is something else in play.  If you show us more code then we may be able to tell you what's wrong.

What I *suspect* may be causing your issue is that you are specifying the directive as camelCase in the html.  When I did that in plunker that I wrote up, it didn't work.  What I normally do when I write my own directive is to write it in 'lower-case' format.

See [the plunker showing the camelCase/lower-case difference](http://plnkr.co/edit/qUmwemlnyPAmkFEsiCeu?p=preview)

Another thing that *can* be causing you issues would be that you used a self-closing tag for the directive, [AngularJs doesn't really support self-closing tags](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953#issuecomment-32206134).

---

Here is my original **wrong** answer:

You need to change the [priority](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) of your custom directive, you want it to be done *after* the `ng-controller` directive.

Comment: That is incorrect usage of `priority`. "The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called"

Answer (score 0):

I think 'ng-transclude' might be the culprit here.

In the directive you might not have mentioned the transclude property, hence its not working.